# assigning variables dynamically in a loop

Tags: python, variables, loops, python-3.x

I need to assign a list of numbers each to a variable from A to Z. However, the length of this list will vary. Is there and way to do this in a loop?
so far i have:

```
file=open('inputfile.txt')
data=file.readlines()

vardict={1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E', 6: 'F',
         7: 'G', 8: 'H', 9: 'I', 10: 'J', 11: 'K', 12: 'L',
         13: 'M', 14: 'N', 15: 'O', 16: 'P', 17: 'Q',
         18: 'R', 19: 'S', 20: 'T', 21: 'U', 22: 'V',
         23: 'W', 24: 'X', 25: 'Y', 26: 'Z'}

for line in data:
    if line[0:1]=='V': #v is a marker that this line needs to assign variables. 
        num=1
        var=line.split() 
        var=var[1:] #remove the tag 
        for entry in var:
            x=vardict[num] #this will assign x to the correct variable
                           #need some lines here to create a variable from whatever is in x 
            num+=1
```

var=['16', '17', '13', '11', '5', '3'] for example, needs to be assigned to variables A to F.
i will need to use those variables a lot in later calculations, so nothing too unwieldy.

EDIT: i will need to use the variables in calculations, until another line with tag V comes up, when i will need to assign the following list to variables A-Z, and use the new variables in later calculations.

input will be of this form:

```
V 1 -2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10
I (A+B)-C*F
I C*F-(A+B)    
R -+AB*CF
V 16 17 13 11 5 3 
O AB+C-D*E/F^
```

where the other lines are various calculations to be made.

Comment: Am I missing something?  This is what arrays (lists or dictionaries, in Python) are for.  Why don't you want to have a list of variables, indexed by a letter from 'A' to 'Z'?  If you insist, you may be able to do what you want with `eval`, but it will be very ugly...

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish? What do you do with `x`? Are you storing them? Right now you are just assigning `vardict[last entry of var]` to `x`.

Comment: you know you can just do `for line in file:` ?

Comment: I just need a way to assign the values in the list to variables A to Z. my only issue is how to do this with a lists of varying size.

Comment: What are you going to use these *for*?

Comment: Assuming you can create the variables, how will you initialize and manipulate their values from the formulas in other lines? Where are the results of the formulas stored and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import string
my_input = "V 1 -2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10"
doctored_input = map(int,my_input.split()[1:])

print dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase,doctored_input))
#result : {'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': -2, 'E': 5, 'D': 4, 'G': 8, 'F': 7, 'I': 10, 'H': 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable named in a string can be assigned by writing to the global dictionary:

```
varname="A"
globals()[varname] = 16   # equivalent to A = 16
```

You can work through the list `var`, generating the strings "A", "B" ... and assigning to each one in turn.

But this sort of trickery is perhaps a sign that you are doing things wrong: It is less explicit and what happens if you run out of letters?

(reference)
http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create an object to hold your variables you can use the setattr function... for example:

```
class variables():
    pass

vars = variables()

for line in data:
    if line[0:1]=='V': #v is a marker that this line needs to assign variables. 
        num=1
        v=line.split() 
        v=v[1:] #remove the tag 
        for entry in var:
            setattr(vars, vardict[num], entry) #creates vars.A=16 for example
            num+=1
```